# How do I restore a deleted file in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, file-recovery

Long story short, I accidently deleted a project which I thought was something else, but not, and I deleted the file from the disk.
 How do I get the file back? Im running Recuva, but are there any other file recovery methods out there?

Comment: You had this project in version control and backed up, right?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, since questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow. And it doesn't directly involve tools used primarily for programming, since you deleted the project from the disk and didn't just remove the project from Eclipse. I would ask this question on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: If you did not say to delete the actual file and folder, you can find your project in eclipse workspace folder. If you did remove permanently, then you cannot recover it.  If your eclipse is still open, you can try Ctrl+Z or undo from menu.

Comment: @Tin OP states "I deleted the file from the disk." Also, "If you did remove permanently, then you cannot recover it." - That's not true, there is plenty of software designed specifically for file recovery.

Comment: @Tin undu-ed but then its only a .project file and a bin folder with a .project

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it (besides martinhh's answer), is to:

- Right click the project
- **Restore from Local History**

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has a local history that is stored in

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.history/
```

I am not sure, if these files are deleted together with the project. I would recommend you check the files by date if you remember when you made the last changes. Or if you remember e.g. a class name you can use grep.

Comment: +1; I had deleted a file in Eclipse a few hours ago that was not visible in the *Restore from Local History* window. Instead I manually checked all directories at the *.history* location and eventually managed to find my lost file there.